# Why would large files not sync with skydrive on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I'm having a problem on Windows 8.1 (new Surface 2 RT if that matters). My SkyDrive has a mix of small (10 lines of text) and large (1.5 meg) files, and all these files happily came down to the Surface from the SkyDrive without any problem. The machine is not domain joined and I sign in only with a Microsoft account.

If I create a new small text file (in Notepad for example) it will sync immediately to the SkyDrive and I can see it using the web view from another machine. But if I use the LAN to get a large text file (1.5 meg) onto the Surface, then add it to SkyDrive, it never syncs up. The new file is labelled as a pending upload on the Surface. I wait 30 minutes or more but the file does not upload and the progress bar never budges (sometimes it says pending and no bar, sometimes uploading and a non moving bar.) I have also tried restarting the Surface but that does not get the sync going. Once in this state it won't do small files either, but if I delete the large file and restart then I can do small files again.

I've tried signing in as another Microsoft account on the Surface and the problem reproduces.

What setting could there be on the machine that would cause this?

Comment: Have you ran a speed test from the Surface?

Comment: No, because the downloads are working perfectly, and it's not that the bar moves slowly it's that it absolutely does not move. I've tried uploading the same file from windows 8 machines to skydrive and it takes less than 5 minutes. Meanwhile on the windows 8.1 machine it never budges from pending. It's not even trying.

Comment: Where you actually able to solve this issue?

Comment: @AndreKraemer no. We settled for moving large files on and off by hand. Suboptimal for sure.